# Best practices for loading large HTML templates through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

`search.js`

```
function search_function() {
     $("#search-button").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#product-container").empty();
     $(".paging_link").empty();
     $("#product-container").html('<div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom: 25px; margin-top: 25px;"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></div>');
     var num;
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/api/search.php',
       async: true,
       data: $('#search-capture').serialize() +"&page=1",
       success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
         $("#product-container").empty();
         array = $.parseJSON(data)
         if(array[1].length > 0)
         {
           num = array[0];
           $.each(array[1], function (index, item) {
             $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '/api/item.php',
               data: {item: item},
               async: false,
               success: function (data) {
                 if(data)
                 {
                     $("#product-container").append(data);
                 }
               }
             });
           });
           $("#search-button").removeAttr('disabled');
           history.pushState(null, null, "search.php?search="+$("#search").val()+"&sort="+$("#sort").val()+"&page=1");
         }
         else {
           num = 0;
           $("#search-button").removeAttr('disabled');
           $("#product-container").append('<div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom: 25px;"><h1>No results for <i>"'+ $("input[name=search]").val() +'"</i>.</h1></div>');
         }
         $(".paging_link").bootpag({
            total: num,
            maxVisible: 5,
            page: 1
         });
      }
     });
   }
```

`/api/item.php`

```
<?php
  include_once("../library/config.php");
  include_once("../library/user.class.php");
  $user = new user($pdo);
  if(isset($_POST['item']))
  {
    $item = $_POST['item'];
    $image_array = json_decode($item['images']);
    $person = $user->person_exists($item['owner_id']);
  }

?>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
  <div class="col-item">
          <div class="post-img-content">
              <img src="<?php echo $image_array[0]; ?>" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"/>
              <span class="post-title">
                  <b><?php echo $item['name'];?></b><br>
              </span>
              <?php
              if($item['price'] > $item['sale_price'])
              {
              ?>
              <span class="round-tag">-<?php echo round(($item['price'] - $item['sale_price'])/$item['sale_price'] * 100); ?>%</span>

              <?php
              }
?>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="price col-md-12">
                      <h5>Offered By: <a href="/user.php?id=<?php echo $item['owner_id']; ?>"><?php echo $person['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $person['lastname']; ?></a></h5>

<?php
if($item['price'] > $item['sale_price'])
{
?>
<div><b>$<?php echo $item['sale_price']; ?></b> <s class="text-muted">$<?php echo $item['price']; ?></s> <br> + $<?php echo $item['shipping']; ?> Shipping</div>

<?php
}
else {
?>
<div><b>$<?php echo $item['price']; ?></b><br> + $<?php echo $item['shipping']; ?> Shipping</div>
<?php
}
?>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <form class="form" name="add-to-cart">

                  <div class="form-group form-group-sm" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $item['id'];?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="quantity" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addtocart">
                  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" id="search-button"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                  <div class="form-group form-group-sm" style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0px;">
                  <a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block"><i class="fa fa-list"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is my Javascript function to get results from an api call, the issue I'm having is load times, because if first makes an AJAX call to `/api/search.php` to get items that I want to display plus all the data such as name, price, seller id etc. Then it does another AJAX call to `/api/item.php` which I have an HTML template that I use PHP and use the data from `POST` to fill the template, and return that html and append it to text. However, this makes it load very slowly since on the second AJAX call, I had to set async to false to load the items in the proper order. I was wondering if there's a more efficient and feasible way to load the item items in without the second AJAX call other than loading the huge block of HTML through Javascript (should I do that instead?).

Comment: best practice is definitely not to use synchronous AJAX, it'll take me a while to sift through the code to suggest an alternative - hopefully somebody better and quicker than me will come along in the meantime :p

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's deprecated since it totally ruins the user experience, but it's a quick fix until I can search an alternative.

Comment: a (possibly) quick fix so you don't use synchronous ajax - https://jsfiddle.net/y8vmuq8p/

Comment: But then the order of the items wouldn't be in order since the items load when the sever fulfills the request, if you look at the main post, I discuss that, that's why async is false right now. Edit: I'll take a look

Comment: no, they would, the fix makes sure each ajax is run in series :p

Comment: It looks like deferred is what I was looking for, thanks! I'll wait for anymore guidance, but you can submit an answer if you want :)

Comment: nah, working on a real solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can insert, in order, placeholder elements, which you can then replace with real content when the ajax completes

all the spans get added synchronously in order, so you have the right location for the eventual data

```
$.each(array[1], function(index, item) {
    var loc = $("#product-container").append("<span/>").children().last();
    // loc is the span just appended
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/item.php',
        data: {
            item: item
        }
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                loc.replaceWith(data); // replace the span with data
            } else {
                loc.remove(); // remove the no longer needed placeholder
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Note: my jQuery is rusty, while I did do simple test of the methodology, I may have stuffed up the jQuery somewhere

Alternatively, if you need to wait for all those ajax to complete before enabling the search-button and history-pushState

```
$.when(array[1].map(function(item) {
    var loc = $("#product-container").append("<span/>").children.last();
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/item.php',
        data: {
            item: item
        }
        success: function(data) {
            if (data) {
                loc.replaceWith(data);
            } else {
                loc.remove();
            }
        }
    });
})).then(function() {
    $("#search-button").removeAttr('disabled');
    history.pushState(null, null, "search.php?search=" + $("#search").val() + "&sort=" + $("#sort").val() + "&page=1");
});
```